# How to set image title for UIView for CAPSPageMenu in objective c

Tags: ios

I am new in IOS and creating an app.
I used CAPSPageMenu for page menu.Menu is working fine but i want to change
title as a image. I searched a lot,but all are negative.

```
PlusTypeViewController *controller1 = [[PlusTypeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlusTableView" bundle:nil];
controller1.title = @"PLUSr";
CapsulesViewController *controller2 = [[CapsulesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CapsulesView" bundle:nil];
controller2.title = @"SUBSTITUTEr";
TabletsViewController *controller3 = [[TabletsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tablets" bundle:nil];
controller3.title = @"SUPPLIERS";
InjectionViewController *controller4 = [[InjectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Injection" bundle:nil];
controller4.title = @"INJECTION";
ShasheViewController *controller5 = [[ShasheViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Shesha" bundle:nil];
controller5.title = @"Shashe";


NSArray *controllerArray2 = @[controller1, controller2,controller3,controller4,controller5];
NSDictionary *parameterss = @{
                              CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionViewBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:112.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor: [UIColor greenColor],

                              CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:112.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                              CAPSPageMenuOptionUnselectedMenuItemLabelColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:112.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor:[UIColor greenColor],
                              CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectedMenuItemLabelColor :[UIColor blackColor],

                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:112.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor blackColor],

                              CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0],
                              CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight: @(30.0),
                              CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidth: @(90.0),
                              //CAPSPageMenuOptionCenterMenuItems: @(YES)
                              };

_secondPageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray2 frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameterss];


[self.view addSubview:_secondPageMenu.view];
```

[image]

PLUSr is a demo title, i want to change it in image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using UIViewController or UITableViewController??

Comment: I am using UIViewController and making custom UIView and using UITableView for table view.

Comment: I cannot understand where you want to change the title.

Comment: if possible provide some more code and screen short for understanding the problem.

Comment: I have added image please check it.

Answer (score 0):

#pragma mark:- Navigation Bar

```
-(void)createCustomNavBar
{

UIView *topBarView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 44)];
topBarView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];
[self.view addSubview:topBarView];


UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.5, 0, 44, 44)];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backs_icon_iPhone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[topBarView addSubview:btnBack];

UIImageView *titleImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
titleImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
titleImageView.frame=CGRectMake(80, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH-160, 44);
[topBarView addSubview:titleImageView];

}
```

this is one of the solution. call this createCustomNavBar mathod. thanks

Comment: Thanks jagveer but you a sharing custom navigation bar. I am using CAPSPageMenu for slide menu pages and for sliding page menu i have to import 2,3 view controllers and then set title name as menu title for particular page.So three title for three pages.But i need to change it as image.

Comment: this was easy way so i share. remain you can do with your requirement sir

Answer (score 0):

You can set image as a title of controller like below code,

First you need to embed `Navigation Controller` for navigate on controller and then write below code in `viewDidLoad` method of that controller

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithName:@"YOUR_IMAGE"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
 imageView.image = image;
 self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Hope this will help you :)

NOTE : I am doing like this in Swift but if any correction for obj-c then pls change it.

Comment: How can i embed navigation controller for every custom xib.All menu is coming from viewcontrollers and they all are imported to one.Please check CAPSPageMenu it will help to understand.

Comment: Ok let me check with that..But if you have property like titleView with this menu then you can apply image like given in my answer. so please check is there any property in which we can apply view?

Answer (score 0):

Navigationitem has titleView property which can be used to set up custom view in our navigation view.

You can make a method like this and call in you viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)setTitleViewForNavigation {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:imageView];
}
```

Comment: sorry its not working please check CAPSPageMenu first.

Answer (score 0):

By using:
 `CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]`